# How to insert a new record for employee if position has changed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which tracks the position of the employee. Each record has a startdate and enddate fields and a whole bunch of other fields.

I have a temporary table and if any of the records in that table update fields (one of the bunch of other fields), I want to set the enddate of the record in the position to that startdate of the record in the temporary table and insert the record in the temporary table into the position table.

Would the following "code" make sense or is there a better way to do it?

```sql
UPDATE saireco.position dst
    SET enddate = src.startdate
FROM tmp src
WHERE (src.employee = dst.employee AND dst.enddate = NULL AND
       (
        src.column1 != dst.column1 OR
        src.column2 != dst.column2
       )
      );

INSERT INTO saireco.position dst
SELECT *
FROM tmp src
WHERE (src.employee = dst.employee AND src.startdate = dst.enddate AND
       (
            src.column1 != dst.column1 OR
            src.column2 != dst.column2
       )
     );
```

EDIT: I have changed the approach a bit and delete all records from temporary table which already exist in the main table so that UPDATE and DELETE will be simpler.

```sql
DELETE FROM tmp t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM saireco.position p
              WHERE t.employee = p.employee
                AND t.column1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM p.column1
                AND t.column2 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM p.column2
              );

UPDATE tmp t
    SET startdate = CURRENT_DATE;

UPDATE saireco.position dst
    SET CASE
          WHEN startdate < src.startdate
             THEN enddate = src.startdate-1
             ELSE enddate = src.startdate
        END
FROM tmp src
WHERE (src.employee = dst.employeeI
   AND dst.endDate = NULL);

INSERT INTO saireco.position
SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Comment: Why use a temp table?

Comment: The temporary table is a staging which loads the data from the HR system. The HR system only provides current position information, so I try to keep a record of position changes. If an employee has a new position, update the old position end date with the start date of the new position and insert a new record into main table.

Comment: Okay, but wouldn't the new position start date be the day after the old position end date? Did you test your SQL?

Comment: Although it *can* do it, SQL is a poor choice for operational processes like this. A tiny bit of app code would sort this out. Can you not use something like a simple python script?

Comment: @Bohemian I am new SQL and have no experience with Python. Is it possible to embed Python code into the database and call it as part of SQL? If you have pointer, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a little [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with the table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: @Orandasoft yes! Postgres supports python: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/plpython.html